# What is the mechanism of a 1,2-hydride shift?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, pericyclic

What is the mechanism of a 1,2-hydride shift? I read that there is an aromatic intermediate, in that the intermediate obeys Hückel's rule.

However, Wikipedia doesn't offer any further explanation. Can someone with more knowledge elaborate on the transition state of a 1,2-hydride shift?